# Distinguishing subparser arguments

Tags: python, argparse

Ok so If I have a parser like this

```
example = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='main parser')
example.add_argument('Kill')

subexample = example.add_subparsers()
person = subexample.add_parser('who')
person.add_argument('name')
person.add_argument('address')
animal = subexample.add_parser('what')
animal.add_argument('name')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

If I use args.name(), what is it going to give me? How can I specify which name I actually want? args.animal.name()? I am unsure, please help. And by the way I don't support killing animals I just didn't have many creative example I could think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [set_defaults](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.set_defaults):

```
import argparse

example = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='main parser')
example.add_argument('Kill')

subexample = example.add_subparsers()
person = subexample.add_parser('who')
person.add_argument('name')
person.add_argument('address')
person.set_defaults(kind = 'person')

animal = subexample.add_parser('what')
animal.add_argument('name')
animal.set_defaults(kind = 'animal')
args = example.parse_args()
print(args)
```

Running yields

```
% test.py 1 who bar baz
Namespace(Kill='1', address='baz', kind='person', name='bar')
% test.py 1 what foo
Namespace(Kill='1', kind='animal', name='foo')
17:31:52 cyrano@farmer:~/test%
```

Comment: I don't really understand. So how could I check to see if the argument was used? Like either person or animal was used. For instance:
    if (args.person != None):
        print "The person argument was used!"

Comment: Check `args.kind`: `if (args.kind == 'person'): print('The person argument was used!')`

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#sub-commands), there is `dest` argument to `add_subparsers()`.
This argument tells in which variable name of the subparser must be stored.

If you use in your code:

```
subexample = example.add_subparsers(dest='parser_name')
```

Then, after parsing arguments you can use them as:

```
if args.parser_name == 'who':
    pass
elif args.parser_name == 'what':
    pass
```